# Selenium Webdriver - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

The following code opens the Chrome but not proceed after it.

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Path to Chrome/chrome.exe");
  WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.msdn.com")
```

Can anyone please help out?

Comment: What version of Chrome? What version of the ChromeDriver?

Comment: this code _Only_ opens chrome.. was there more code that went with this? if so, please share

Answer (score 1):

You need to point webdriver.chrome.driver at chromedriver.exe, not at Chrome itself.

Chrome driver is a separate application which implements the wire protocol between your selenium test and Chrome.

It's available for download here: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/